# Дубляж текста при отображении на HTML странице с помощью Freemarker

Tags: java, html, servlet, wildfly, freemarker

Есть сайт. Он написан на Java. Запускаю локально с помощью сервера WildFly. Использую Freemarker как шаблонизатор. Вот как генерирую страницу в классе сервлета:

[image]

Вот то указаны теги для шаблонизатора в HTML файле

```
  <div class="service-info-pod_block">
    <div class="service-topic">
       <#list post as post>
            <#if post.serviceTopick??>
                <h3>${post.serviceTopick}</h3>
            </#if>
        </#list>
    </div>
```

При первой загрузке страницы после деплоя отображается все корректно. Но после перезагрузки страницы появляется вот такой вот дубляж текста и всего того, что добавляется с помощью Freemarkr'a

[image]

Что нужно поменять в HTML коде, что бы шаблонизатор не делал дубляжей?

Comment: Сбросьте html код.

Comment: @RomanC Я добавил фрагмент кода.

Comment: Уберите макросы из него.

Comment: @Roman Но если я их уберу, то не смогу добавить текст?

Comment: Приведите пример кода, ошибки, кототую можно воспроизвести.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конфликт имен при обработке шаблона.

```
<#list post as post>
```

должно быть

```
<#list post as posts>
```

и вообще это надо писать один раз на странице - сразу после

```
<div class="service-container">
```

---

контроллер не является потоко-безопасным, поэтому не должен содержать полей

```
@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    Service service = new Service("Лаборатория", "resources/images/lab.jpg", "Лаборатория", "Одним из найболее эфективных этапов " +
        "\tобследования Вашего питомца является лабораторные иследования, что позволяет " +
        "максимально точно и быстро поставить диагноз.");
    List<Service> data = new ArrayList<>();

    data.add(service);
    resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8;");
    req.setAttribute("posts", data);
    req.getRequestDispatcher("resources/pages/Services.html").forward(req, resp);
}
```